# Authorization by login / password does not work when connecting via JMX

Tags: java, jmx, activemq-artemis

I have a method whose parameters are passed values for connecting to the ActiveMQ Artemis broker via the JMX protocol. But my username/password is not working. That is, if I leave the user and password values empty, then it will still connect, and I want an error to pop up when connecting to the queue since the user data is incorrect

```java
public static MBeanServerConnection connectBroker(String brokerUrl, String user, String password) {
    try {
        Map<String, String[]> env = new HashMap();
        String[] creds = {user, password};
        env.put(JMXConnector.CREDENTIALS, creds);
        JMXConnector connector = JMXConnectorFactory.connect(new JMXServiceURL("service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://" + brokerUrl + ":13682/jmxrmi"), env);
        return connector.getMBeanServerConnection();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

It's strange that if CREDENTIALS is passed, it still works, but I want it to give an error if there is no such user

`broker.xml`:

```xml
<configuration xmlns="urn:activemq" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:activemq /schema/artemis-configuration.xsd">
   <core xmlns="urn:activemq:core">
        <name>localhost</name>
      <bindings-directory>./data/messaging/bindings</bindings-directory>

      <journal-directory>./data/messaging/journal</journal-directory>

      <large-messages-directory>./data/messaging/largemessages</large-messages-directory>

      <paging-directory>./data/messaging/paging</paging-directory>


      <!-- true to expose ActiveMQ Artemis resources through JMX -->
      <jmx-management-enabled>true</jmx-management-enabled>

      <!-- Acceptors -->
      <acceptors>
         <acceptor name="netty">tcp://localhost:61616</acceptor>
      </acceptors>

      <!-- Other config -->

      <security-settings>
         <!--security for example queue-->
         <security-setting match="exampleQueue">
            <permission roles="amq" type="createDurableQueue"/>
            <permission roles="amq" type="deleteDurableQueue"/>
            <permission roles="amq" type="createNonDurableQueue"/>
            <permission roles="amq" type="deleteNonDurableQueue"/>
            <permission roles="amq" type="consume"/>
            <permission roles="amq" type="send"/>
            <permission roles="amq" type="browse"/>
         </security-setting>
         <security-setting match="TestQueue">
            <permission roles="amq" type="createDurableQueue"/>
            <permission roles="amq" type="deleteDurableQueue"/>
            <permission roles="amq" type="createNonDurableQueue"/>
            <permission roles="amq" type="deleteNonDurableQueue"/>
            <permission roles="amq" type="consume"/>
            <permission roles="amq" type="send"/>
         </security-setting>
         <security-setting match="TestQueueSecond">
            <permission roles="amq" type="createDurableQueue"/>
            <permission roles="amq" type="deleteDurableQueue"/>
            <permission roles="amq" type="createNonDurableQueue"/>
            <permission roles="amq" type="deleteNonDurableQueue"/>
            <permission roles="amq" type="consume"/>
            <permission roles="amq" type="send"/>
         </security-setting>
      </security-settings>

      <addresses>
         <address name="exampleQueue">
            <anycast>
               <queue name="exampleQueue"/>
            </anycast>
         </address>
         <address name="TestQueue">
            <anycast>
               <queue name="TestQueue"/>
            </anycast>
         </address>
         <address name="TestQueueSecond">
            <anycast>
               <queue name="TestQueueSecond"/>
            </anycast>
         </address>
      </addresses>
   </core>
</configuration>
```

`management.xml`:

```
<management-context xmlns="http://activemq.apache.org/schema">
   <connector connector-port="13682" connector-host="localhost"/>
   <authorisation>
      <allowlist>
         <entry domain="hawtio"/>
      </allowlist>
      <default-access>
         <access method="list*" roles="view,update,amq,guest"/>
         <access method="get*" roles="view,update,amq,guest"/>
         <access method="is*" roles="view,update,amq,guest"/>
         <access method="set*" roles="update,amq,guest"/>
         <access method="*" roles="amq,guest"/>
      </default-access>
      <role-access>
         <match domain="org.apache.activemq.artemis">
            <access method="list*" roles="view,update,amq,guest"/>
            <access method="get*" roles="view,update,amq,guest"/>
            <access method="is*" roles="view,update,amq,guest"/>
            <access method="set*" roles="update,amq,guest"/>
            <access method="*" roles="amq,guest"/>
         </match>
         <!--example of how to configure a specific object-->
         <!--<match domain="org.apache.activemq.artemis" key="subcomponent=queues">
            <access method="list*" roles="view,update,amq"/>
            <access method="get*" roles="view,update,amq"/>
            <access method="is*" roles="view,update,amq"/>
            <access method="set*" roles="update,amq"/>
            <access method="*" roles="amq"/>
         </match>-->
      </role-access>
   </authorisation>
</management-context>
```

`login.config`:

```
activemq {
   org.apache.activemq.artemis.spi.core.security.jaas.PropertiesLoginModule sufficient
       debug=false
       reload=true
       org.apache.activemq.jaas.properties.user="artemis-users.properties"
       org.apache.activemq.jaas.properties.role="artemis-roles.properties";
    
   org.apache.activemq.artemis.spi.core.security.jaas.GuestLoginModule sufficient
       debug=false
       org.apache.activemq.jaas.guest.user="admin"
       org.apache.activemq.jaas.guest.role="amq";
};
```

Comment: Can you add your login.config to the question?

Comment: I have added the login.config file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `login.config` is using the `GuestLoginModule`, i.e.:

```
   org.apache.activemq.artemis.spi.core.security.jaas.GuestLoginModule sufficient
       debug=false
       org.apache.activemq.jaas.guest.user="admin"
       org.apache.activemq.jaas.guest.role="amq";
```

This means that users who don't pass any credentials or pass the wrong credentials will be accepted and given the username `admin` and the role `amq`. See [the documentation](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/security.html#guestloginmodule) for more details.

If you don't want this behavior you can use this in your `login.config` instead:

```
activemq {
   org.apache.activemq.artemis.spi.core.security.jaas.PropertiesLoginModule required
       debug=false
       reload=true
       org.apache.activemq.jaas.properties.user="artemis-users.properties"
       org.apache.activemq.jaas.properties.role="artemis-roles.properties";
};
```